# tmux doesn't search scrollback across line breaks

Tags: tmux

Maybe something is wrong with my configuration, but when I search my tmux scrollback by typing:

```
prefix-[
/
<search target>
```

instances of *search target* that are interrupted by line breaks (because the tmux pane or terminal window is too narrow or *search target* is very long, or it's just bad luck) are not found. If I resize the pane so that an instance of *search target* is not interrupted by a line break, then tmux finds it.

Is there a way to perform a search with tmux that finds stuff in wrapped lines?

By the way, this is a pretty bad bug and reduces my confidence in tmux. It should not be possible to perform a search, regardless of method or configuration, that fails to finds instances of the search target. Searches are often used to confirm the presence or absence of something, and in a way tmux is providing a false negative test result. I guess I should stick with grepping files to be safe. I know there is a way to put the tmux scrollback in a file.

Kind of sad.

Comment: What version of tmux? Seems to work fine for me, with tmux 2.1.

Comment: tmux 2.1, iTerm2 2.1.4, OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Maybe an OSX specific issue? Out of ideas, I don't have OSX. Sorry.

Comment: @PenguinBrian That's useful information. What OS are you using?

Comment: Also, opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/296

Comment: I tested with Debian stable and testing.

Comment: This is still an issue 8 years later. Sad...

Comment: I think maybe some versions of tmux now have a fix for this. I haven't used tmux in a long time, and it's kind of hard to tell from GitHub issues and commit messages, but see [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2570) and [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3864) (and if you want to look deeper, [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/296#issuecomment-180281848) and [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/831c67c2d8d18817f93d973ee9ab3b4f174f9dcd)).